# how to solve that a page is not postback even all validation is validated using jquery validation engine on sharepoint server 2007?

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint-2007, jquery-validate

I have complex form and in page a submit button, it has events for both client and server side.

After first time clicking on button, validation class is added and then validation error message is shown,

and then filling to a required field to be validated, and click on button again, page is not post back, even jquery validation engine works well.

In my local computer, page is postback after filled to a required field. I assume, both client side and serverside work.

But not on sever, page is not post back after filled to a required field.

This is my code. I am looking forward your replies and suggestions.

==========================================================================

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery("#aspnetForm").validationEngine();

    //btmContinous
    $('#ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_Form1_btmContinous').click(function () {
        //Part A
    var className = $('#ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_Form1_txtA2').attr('class');
        alert(className);

        if (!(className == "validate[required] text-input"))        
        { 
    alert(className);

        $('#ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_Form1_txtA2').addClass("validate[required] text-input");

       }

if ( $("#Form1").validationEngine('validate') == true) {
         alert("true");             
     //$('#ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_Form1_txtA2').removeClass("validate[required] text-input");
    //should  post back here

    }
else{alert("false");}       

    });
```

Comment: Did you debug with Web Developer Toolbar and see what's happening?

Answer (score 0):

It was yesterday i was having the same issue. My validation will not work after postback.

Page contained update panel and all validations on button click inside document.ready.

The validation will not work after postback.

What i did is put the validation i.e

```
$("#<%= Button1.ClientID %>").click(function() {
    //// Validation conditions here
});
```

inside the Sys.Application.add_load() function and it started working after postback too.

So now code looked like

```
Sys.Application.add_load(function() {
    $("#<%= Button1.ClientID %>").click(function() {
        //// Validation conditions here
    });
}
```

More about what happens can be read here

http://www.codeoutlaw.com/2009/11/use-sysapplicationaddload-instead-of.html

Hopefully this helps someone :)